# How to add padding between TextField border and the scroll bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, textfield

This is my current code:

```
  Widget _buildContent(TextStyle _textStyle6) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Focus(
          onFocusChange: (hasFocus) => setState(() => focused = hasFocus),
          child: widget.scrollController != null 
            ? Scrollbar(
              controller: widget.scrollController,
              thickness: 10,
              trackVisibility: true,
              thumbVisibility: true,
              radius: Radius.circular(8),
              child: _buildTextField(_textStyle6),
            ) 
            : _buildTextField(_textStyle6),
        ),
        if (widget.outerHintText != null) Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, top: 6),
          child: Text(widget.outerHintText!, style: widget.outerHintStyle),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextField(TextStyle _textStyle6) {
    return TextFormField(
      style: _textStyle6,
      maxLength: widget.maxLength,
      minLines: widget.minLines,
      maxLines: widget.maxLines,
      keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
      scrollController: widget.scrollController,
      // scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        alignLabelWithHint: widget.alignLabelWithHint,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 0.8),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff1a73e8), width: 2),
        ),
        labelText: widget.label,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: focused ? Color(0xff1a73e8) : Colors.black),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 20),
        prefixIcon: widget.prefixIcon,
        prefixIconColor: widget.prefixIconColor,
        constraints: widget.constraints,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Widget returned like this:

[image]

I wanna add some padding between the right border of TextField and the scrollbar. How to get it?

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap it with ScrollbarTheme and set crossAxisMargin:

```
const ScrollbarTheme(
  data: ScrollbarThemeData(crossAxisMargin: 10),
  child: Scrollbar(
    thickness: 10,
    trackVisibility: true,
    thumbVisibility: true,
    child: TextField(),
  ),
);
```

Alternatively, you may use RawScrollbar and set crossAxisMargin:

```
const RawScrollbar(
  thickness: 10,
  trackVisibility: true,
  thumbVisibility: true,
  crossAxisMargin: 5,
  child: TextField(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
      right: 10.0,
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(),
      border: Border.all(
        color: Color(),
      ),
    ),
    child: Scrollbar(
      thickness: 5.0,
      controller: _scrollController,
      trackVisibility: true,
      thumbVisibility: true,
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: 8,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
        scrollController: _scrollController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: '....',
          hintStyle: TextStyles.bodyTextLight,
          isDense: true,
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Color(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

You can do something like this, wrap your textfield and scrollbar to a container and give that container the same border and background style to it which you are giving to the textfield. And give it padding on the right side of the container.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2XIg.png

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me was:

```
RawScrollbar(
controller:  _textFieldScrollController,
thumbColor: Colors.red,
thumbVisibility: true,
shape: StadiumBorder( side: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber, width: 1.0)),
padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8,top: 20),
child: TextFormField(
scrollController: _textFieldScrollController,
controller: commentBoxController,
...
))
```